# Dynamics AX 2012 SSRS Report Page Size

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ssrs-2012

I need to set the page size of the SSRS Report I'm currently doing to 
**

> Portrait/Width = 8.5in/Height = 5.5in

I've tried setting this up in the report properties but as per my observation, the moment the height becomes lower than the width, SSRS will automatically convert it to Landscape.

Any workaround to fix this would be a great help.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Did you check your AX version? According to [SSRS report not printing in Landscape](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/106577) there is a problem with the orientation report property in AX 2012 CU4 and below. Also did you check this only with printing to screen or did you also check printing to pdf or a physical printer?

Comment: the AX version is AX 2012 R2. yes, we've printed on physical printer/in screen and exported it in pdf. all of them gives the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is workaround:

1. Set in Visual Studio page width and height that you need.
2. Override preRunModifyContract method in controller class so:

   ```
   protected void preRunModifyContract() {
         this.parmReportContract().parmPrintSettings().printLandscape(false);

         super();
   }
   ```